# Interaction term in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, interaction

I have a question about interaction terms in logistic regression. I have a dummy dependent variable and 2 predictors in the model. Predictor A with 2 levels and predictor B with 3 levels. In an output table in SPSS software I can't find all interaction terms, it just shows 2 interactions rather than 5 interactions. Why is that?
for more descriptions:
I have these data: Protein intake (High intake versus Low intake) Geno-type (AA, AG, GG) The ref are (High intake and AA) The spss outcome showed the odds ratio just for (Low intake protein,GG) and (Low intake protein,AG). I should also can find the odds ratio for (High intake, GG) and (High intake and AG). But I couldn't find the later results. Why is that?

Comment: You seem to have created a second account by accident - [see here for hope to merge your accounts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This will let you edit your own posts.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 2):

SPSS is showing the right output. There are only 2 estimable interactions in the situation you describe.

This is similar to the case with one categorical independent variable. If it has p levels you can only have p-1 dummy variables.  With two IVs, one which has 3 levels and the other 2, the first has only 2 dummy variables, the second has only one, and so, there are 2x1 interaction terms.

Comment: One level is used as reference so there are indeed less odds ratios. It might be that the papers you refer to have also reported the reference categories?